# SVN server on an Amazon machine started refusing connection

Tags: svn, svnserve

Today, out of the blue one of our team mates tried committing to our SVN repo and the SVN server replied with:

`Error running context: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.`

The server is hosted on an Amazon EC2 linux instance. Our repo was accessible via http protocol. Can svn provide http access by other means? If so which? How can I debug this issue?

Thanks

EDIT:
I found the apache service (httpd) - it wasn't running. Duh.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why, but the apache service (httpd) has stopped. I restarted it (`sudo -u root service httpd start`) and everything went back to normal.